# Can a Choice selection in a template be used to set another property

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2022, template-engine

Working in VS 2022

When creating a template using the new template engine I can create Parameters with a datatype of choice. In the eventual templates these are shown as a dropdown.

Currently in my template.json I have the following

```
"LoggingFramework": {
"type": "parameter",
"datatype": "choice",
"defaultValue": "Serilog",
"Choices": [
  {
    "choice": "Serilog",
    "description": "Adds the Serilog logging framework to the project"
  },
  {
    "choice": "Nlog",
    "description": "Adds the Nlog logging framework to the project"
  }
],
"replaces": "Nlog"
}
```

In theory I should then be able to use a conditional in the actual template along these lines

```
#if (LoggingFramework == "Serilog")
//something here
#endif
```

That always seems to give me an Invalid pre processor error.

Most of the samples of pre processor conditionals do appear to assume that the conditional is a boolean,  If that is indeed the case is there a way to set another boolean parameter in the template.json which uses the value from the choice parameter?